# Proof verification: classification of free abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $X$={$a_i| i\in I$} be a set. Then the free abelian group $F$ on $X$ is isomorphic to the group $G$ defined by generators $X$ and the relations {$a_ia_ja_i^{-1}a_j^{-1}=e| i,j\in I$}.

There is already a solution on this website [free abelian group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1053021/free-abelian-group), and [Exercise on characterization of free abelian groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/906238/exercise-on-characterization-of-free-abelian-groups?rq=1), but I did not find them so routine as my brief solution:

$G$ is abelian since its generators commute. If $a_1^{p_1}...a_s^{p_s}$ as a member of $G$ (where $a_i$'s are distinct as members of $X$) is in $ker \phi$ where $\phi$ is the Van Dyck’s epimorphism from $G$ to $F$ then $p_1a_1+...p_sa_s$=0 in $F$ so that each $p_i$ is 0 since $F$ is free abelian, so that $\phi$ is a monomorphism as well.

Is my solution correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "classification".

Your proof that $G$ is free abelian is correct, but you might want to reconsider the exposition a bit, since it sounds vaguely circular (even though it isn't).

Of course, there are a lot of ways of describing the free abelian groups.  They are also just the free $\Bbb{Z}$-modules, which are just direct sums of copies of $\Bbb{Z}$.

Since $\Bbb{Z}$ is commutative, direct sums of different cardinalities give *non-isomorphic* free modules, since commutative rings have invariant basis number.  To me, you need this additional result (that all the items on the list are distinct) to say that you have *classified* the free abelian groups.

I should add that the only proofs I know of the last paragraph require ZFC.  There are probably models of ZF that break it.

Comment: My mere intention was to show that $G$ and $F$ are isomorphic, so the title of my question is badly worded

Comment: Do you mean for the classification I should add that $G$ is determined up to isomorphism by the cardinality of $X$?

Comment: Well, you already have that.  I mean that you also want that the cardinality of $X$ is determined by the isomorphism class of $G$.